# Как правильно организовать логику добавления данных в БД JS , ajax, php

Tags: javascript, ajax

Пишу вэб приложение по созданию списка задач, немогу понять как организовать добавление в БД задачи.

У меня есть два варианта:

1) Жму добавить задачу и данные через ajax улетают в php и в БД, далее надо чтоб задача сразу же появилась в списке на экране (без перезагрузки ) соответственно вторым запросом все задачи прилетают из БД. при этом у меня стоит датапикер JQ и чтобы он обновился тоже используется ajax - то есть получается три запроса занимающих время, на локал хосте все быстро работает а вот в инете есть задержка.

2) второй вариант - при загрузке страницы получить сразу все задачи в массив и вывести их и при добавлении задачи ajaxом отправлять их в БД и JS одновременно добавлять задачу в массив который уже загружен. Мне кажется это более быстрый и логичный вариант , но как это сделать если в бд у каждой задачи уникальный ID????????????????

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-an-api-centric-web-application--net-23417

Comment: Ну и, надо понимать, что вы не первый задавший тут вопрос про создание todolist, так что [поищите в базе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=todo) подходящий вам ответ.

Comment: спасибо конечно, но поиском я умею пользоваться, а вот ответа на свой вопрос я так и не нашел

Comment: Здорово! Но, видите ли, пока вы никого не убедили потратить время отвечая на ваш вопрос. Так что [поделитесь результатом вашего поиска и расскажите, что вы нашли и почему найденные ответы вас не устроили. Это продемонстрирует вашу способность думать самостоятельно, поможет избежать повторяющихся очевидных ответов и, самое важное, увеличит шансы на получение точного ответа!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#help-post-body)

Comment: если у вас нет ответа можете просто пропустить этот вопрос, над этой задачей я думаю уже несколько месяцев, если вы обратите внимание у меня ник Чайник, логично что я в этом ничего не понимаю и даже не могу корректный запрос сделать так как вероятно не знаю как называется то что мне нужно, по этому я описал проблему тут как сумел. вместо того чтобы делать советы не по теме могли бы просто пройти момо